# what is function(var1)(var2) in python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code I pulled from someone I don't understand:

```
def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        wraps(func)(self)
```

I've seen things like `wraps(func)(self)` several times but never seen it explained. How is there a function with parameters and then another `(var)` thing after it? What does it all mean? Thank you

Comment: In your particular example, that is almost certainly a usage of [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which is a helper for creating decorators. (It does some handy stuff to make sure the right function names are used during logging, for example.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Functions are [**first-class objects**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in Python.

You have no doubt encountered this on the command line if you have typed the name only of a function without parentheses.

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: <function __main__.a>
```

When you see `a(b)(c)` it is a method of chaining:

- The function `a` is defined to return *another function*.
- `a(b)` calls `a` and returns that reference (to a callable function)
- `a(b)(c)` calls whatever function was returned by `a` with `c` as an argument.

This is equivalent to the following:

```
new_func = a(b)
new_func(c)
```

---

An example:

```
In [1]: def multiply_by(x):
   ...:     def multiply_by_x(y):
   ...:         return x * y
   ...:     return multiply_by_x    # notice no parens
   ...: 

In [2]: multiply_by(10)
Out[2]: <function __main__.multiply_by_x>
```

Notice when you call this you get a **function object**. (This is what I mean when I am saying a "reference to a function" or the like.)

```
In [3]: multiply_by(10)(5)
Out[3]: 50
```

You're calling the function returned by `multiply_by()` with 5 as an argument, and it's exactly the same as doing:

```
In [4]: multiply_by_10 = multiply_by(10)

In [5]: multiply_by_10(4)
Out[5]: 40

In [6]: multiply_by_10(8)
Out[6]: 80
```

The cool thing about doing this, as you can see from this example, is that now your `multiply_by` function is a factory for functions that multiply by something. Above, we created `multiply_by_10` which, obviously, multiplies what you feed it by 10. We can just as easily do:

```
In [7]: multiply_by_5 = multiply_by(5)
```

and have a function that multiplies by 5. This is obviously extremely useful. Incidentally, it's also how Python's [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) work.

*Thanks @MarkusMeskanen in the comments for pointing out a way to make my silly example into a cooler one!*

See also:

- [What is a closure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/what-is-a-closure)
- [Python Decorators Demystified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/2588818)
- [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)

Comment: I think a bit better, or at least more useful example would be something like this: http://pastebin.com/afJHmtNs

Comment: This might be clearer if you changed `example_func` to actually use `x`, which would also give you the chance to explain closures, which most useful function objects are going to be.

Comment: These are both excellent ideas and I will add them. Keep an eye out for corrections as I make edits please.

Comment: so it seems if a(b) out of the a(b)(c) doesn't return a function, but an integer or somethin, it'll blow up?

Comment: Haha if by "blow up" you mean raise `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, then yes!

Comment: exactly, that's cool I blew through it because my decorator worked but I'll try to use these

Answer (score 3):

The key is that `wraps()` takes a function as its parameter and returns a function, probably with some extra goodness added to it, sort of like what a [*decorator function*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) does.

If you were to `print(wraps(func))` you should see output that identifies the object as a function.

So `wraps(func)(self)` can be rewritten as

```
wrapped_func = wraps(func)
wrapped_func(self)
```

which looks more "normal" to some people.

Answer (score 2):

You case is that the function `wrap` returns a callable, i.e. a function or a class or any object that implements the `__call__` method. So just to understand take a look at this example:

```
def wraps(arg):
   def decor(func):
      print(arg)
      return func
   return decor
```

This is a typical decorator, meaning that you can do the following:

```
@wrap('some arg')
def func(a):
    print(a)
```

So what happens here is the following:

1. First the `wrap` function is being called with the argument value `some arg`. As you can the inside wrap we have another `decor` function defined, which is being returned
2. Whatever is returned from the `wrap` function, is being called, i.e. the `__call__` method is being invoked on the returned object, with the argument being the function being decorated. In this case we have `decor(func)`.
3. Our `decor` function simply prints the value of `arg` (`'some arg'` in our case), and return the `func`.

**Note**: This is being done only once!

```
func('hello1')
func('hello2')
```

...you will get the following output

```
some arg
hello1
hello2
```